# What do I do with this legacy weapon unlock?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So, 1.2 is here and suddenly all those legacy levels mean something. Somehow in the deluge of info, I missed the part where they told me what to with the legacy main hand weapon parts they mailed me.  So... anybody want to post that up here, so I can make this weapon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At capital worlds (coruscant/Dromund Kaas) there are 4 new legacy vendors (Senate Tower square/ Kaas City Square), You can exchange this kit you got for one mainhand weapon 14-16 lvl.

Comment: oh so basically it's some thing I'll use for about three hours... best reward ever!